# Why I cannot center a div directly in the body?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was trying to use a little bit flex box, and I have been trying to understand how to do basic things, but I am not able to center a `div` directly in the `body`, but I am able to center for example a `p` element inside a `div`.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="center.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <p class="intro">This is a HTML template file.</p>          
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

And this is the CSS file:

```
body{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;

}

.parent{
    margin: auto;

    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;

    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;

}

.intro{
    margin: auto;
    color: darkblue;
}
```

Basically I am applying the same technique as for centering the `p` element inside the `div` element...

This does not work either on Safari or Chrome.

Comment: you need to set width and height to 100% to html, then body in order to see it working on full page. add body{border:solid;) and see where it stands :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks, that worked! But why do we need to mess up with the html tag? I thought the body represented the real content...

Comment: flex shrinks element on its content. Percentage value for width and height needs a parent with values set, else it is % of null. HTML takes the viewport size as reference :) so viewport size values cascads down to body via html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `width` and `height` to `100%` to `html` and `body`, in order to see it working on full page.

Add to your code:

```
body{ 
  border:solid; 
}
```

and see where it stands!

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="intro">This is a HTML template file.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
body {
  background: #900;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  /*
  This doesn't work
  margin-left: -25%;
  margin-top: -25%;
  */

  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;

  padding: 20px;  
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BvdgL).

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.className').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : -$('.className').outerWidth()/2,
        'margin-top' : -$('.className').outerHeight()/2
    });
});
```